# Approximation by polynomials

Tags: approximation-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fa.functional-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^n$. Let $ x_0, ..., x_m$ be different numbers from $[a,b]$.

Does for each $\varepsilon >0$ there exist a polynom $P$ such that $P^{(k)}(x_i)=f^{(k)}(x_i)$ for $i=0,...,m$, $k=0,...,n$ 
and $sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)-P(x)|< \varepsilon$?

Comment: I have never found an adequate reference for what one would call a "differentiable Stone--Weierstrass theorem",
but I would assume that such a thing exists.

However, I do happen to know a theorem found in Real Algebraic Manifolds by J. Nash that say:

Let $f: U \rightarrow \R^n$ be analytic, let $A\subseteq U$ be compact and bounded by an analytic manifold. 
Then there exists a sequence of polynomials $\{f_n\}$ so that for any $\alpha$:
\[
D^\alpha f_n \rightarrow D^\alpha f
\]
I don't know much about Fourier series,
which appear in the proof.
Maybe it works with $C^n$ in place of $C^\omega$.

Comment: @Malte: this is true. See mathoverflow.net/questions/85153/…. But I think that the OT wants something different: a uniform approximation of the function and exact value of the function and derivatives at the given points. It is not required that the derivative converges uniformly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem may be split into two independent and classical ones: the Hermite interpolation, and the  Weierstrass approximation.

First, we want a polynomial $p\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ with given derivatives  at some given nodes $x _ 0,\dots, x _ m $. This is an instance of the [Hermite interpolation problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation); yours has exactly one solution $p$ with $ \operatorname{deg}(p) < (m+1)(n+1) $ (the degree one would expect in  terms of number of linear conditions).
So, given your $f\in C^n$, you can find a polynomial with $p^{(j)}(x _ i)=f^{(j)}(x _ i)$ for all $0 \le i \le m$ and $0 \le j \le n$.

Second, as a consequence,
$$\frac{f(x)-p(x)}{\prod _ {i=0}^ m(x- x _ i)^n}$$
is (extends to) a continuous function on $[a,b]$ that vanishes on the points $x _ i$. By the Stone-Weierstrass approximation theorem there is a polynomial vanishing on the points $x _ i$ as well, whose uniform distance from that function on the interval $[a,b]$ is less than, say,  $\epsilon (b-a)^{-n(m+1)}$. In other words, there is a polynomial $q\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that

$$\bigg\| \frac{f(x)-p(x)}{\prod _ {i=0}^ m(x- x _ i)^n} - q(x) \prod _ {i=0} ^ m(x- x _ i) \bigg\|_{\infty, [a,b]}  < \epsilon (b-a)^{-n(m+1)}\ , $$

therefore the polynomial $P(x):= p(x)+ q(x) \prod _ {i=0} ^ m(x- x _ i) ^{n+1}$ fullfills the requirements, for  $P^{(j)}(x _ i)=p^{(j)}(x _ i)=f^{(j)}(x _ i)$ for all $0 \le i \le m$ and $0 \le j \le n$, and 
$$\|f- P\|_{\infty,[a,b]} < \epsilon\  .$$

**btw.** Incidentally, some time ago I happen to notice that one can find the solution of the Hermite interpolation problem as an application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem in the ring of polynomials, and wrote [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Applications) the details.

**edit.** As to why  The set $A$ of all polynomial functions on $[a,b]$ that vanish at given points $x_0,\dots, x_m$ is dense in all continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that vanish in $x_0,\dots, x_r$.  One way, a bit abstract but quite immediate is, to see it as a corollary of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem  (A separating closed algebra of real valued functions on a compact space  $X$ is either $C(X)$ or a maximal ideal $M_x\subset C(X)$, the set of all functions vanishing at  $x$). Consider $X=$ the topological quotient of $[a,b]$ obtained identifying all points $x_i$ to a point $\xi$. All functions in $A$ factor through  to the quotient map, and define a closed separating algebra of continuous functions  on $X$ that vanish on the identified point $\xi$. Thus, this algebra contains all continuous functions on $X$ that vanish on $\xi$, which is the thesis read on the quotient.

Note that the same construction holds in general, and provides a characterization of all closed algebras $A$ of continuous functions on a compact space $X$: identifying all points that are not distinguished by the functions of $A$ (that is, under the equivalence relation $x R_A y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $f\in A$) one gets a  Hausdorff compact quotient space (whether or not $X$ is Hausdorff), and the quotient map $\pi: X\to X/{R _ A}$ induces an isometric isomorphism of algebras $f\mapsto f\circ \pi$ of either $C(X/{R_A})$ or a maximal ideal of it onto $A$; conversely, any Hausdorff quotient of $X$ produces a closed sub-algebra of $C(X)$ this way.

Another way to see it is as a corollary of the classic Weierstrass theorem: Consider $P$ as in your comment below, then add a perturbation $L$ that makes $P+L$ vanish on the points $\{x_i\}$; this has been clearly explained in Ilya Bogdanov's answer. Here you don't have derivatives and $L$ is just a Lagrange interpolation polynomial, which is small in the uniform norm because it is small on the points  $\{x_i\}$.

Comment: Very thanks. I have one question. You used the following fact: if a continuous function $g:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ vanishes at points $x_0,...,x_m$ then for every $\delta >0$ there exists a polynomial $Q$
which vanishes at $x_0,...,x_m$ such that $\|g(x)-Q(x)\|_{sup} <\delta$.  It is easy for $m=0$, because by Weierstrass threorem we find polynomial $P$ such that $\|f-P\| <\frac{\delta}{2}$ and polynomial $Q:=P-P(x_0)$ will be good. How to prove its for $m\geq 1$?



Comment: I've edit and added a few lines on this point.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that $[a,b]=[0,1]$. $C^k$ always means $C^k[0,1]$. We will even approximate $f$ in $C^n$-norm satisfying your additional condition.

1. As was mentioned in the comments, you can easily approximate $f$ together with all its derivatives up to $n$th uniformly by a polynomial. In fact, it is enough to approximate $f^{(n)}$ with an adequate accuracy: if $||f'-P'||_C<\varepsilon$ and $f(0)=P(0),$ then $||f-P||_C<\varepsilon.$
2. Now take the polynomials $Q_{ik}(x)$ such that $Q_{ik}^{(d)}(x_j)=0$ for all $d=0,\dots,n$ 
   and $j=0,\dots,m$ except that $Q_{ik}^{(k)}(x_i)=1$. Such polynomials are easy to construct: for instance, one may take 
   $$
     Q_{ik}(x)=c_{ik}(x-x_i)^k\prod_{j\neq i}\left((x-x_i)^{n+1}-(x_j-x_i)^{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\;\;
   $$ 
   for a suitable constant $c_{ik}.$ Let $M=\max_{i,k}||Q_{ik}||_{C^n}.$ Then, let the approximation in the previous paragraph be $\delta$-accurate with $\delta=\varepsilon/(2M(m+1)(n+1)).$ To correct the values of the polynomial and its derivatives at $x_i,$ it is enough to add the polynomials $Q_{ik}$ multiplied by the coefficients with absolute values $\leq\delta,$ hence the total error will be not more that $\delta+(m+1)(n+1)M\delta<\varepsilon.$

Comment: nice          !           